# LayoutTransition: Animate View next to an expanding View

Tags: android, android-animation

I've recreated my problem to a very simple representation. I have 3 TextViews. 2 of them are in a seperate `LinearLayout`, the third is on the same level as the `LinearLayout`.
I'm toggling the visibility of `test1` and `test2`, and I'd like to see them fade away (which works). Furthermore, I want `test3` to slide into his new place (taking place of `test1` and `test2`). I can't make this happen. `test3` just snaps to it's new point.

How can I achive this?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click" />

    <LinearLayout android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/child1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my Activity:

```
public class LayoutAnimations extends Activity {
    private boolean toggle = true;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_animations);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toggle) {
                    findViewById(R.id.test1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.test2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.test1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.test2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

***Edit: I actually have another `TextView` next to `test1` and `test2` which should be visible at all times, so I can't just hide the `LinearLayout` itself.***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved it using an other question. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984525/675383)

Quoting:

I believe the simplest approach is to extend `Animation` class and override `applyTransformation()` to change the view's height as follows:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyCustomAnimation extends Animation {

    public final static int COLLAPSE = 1;
    public final static int EXPAND = 0;

    private View mView;
    private int mEndHeight;
    private int mType;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    public MyCustomAnimation(View view, int duration, int type) {

        setDuration(duration);
        mView = view;
        mEndHeight = mView.getHeight();
        mLayoutParams = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams());
        mType = type;
        if(mType == EXPAND) {
            mLayoutParams.height = 0;
        } else {
            mLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return mView.getHeight();
    }

    public void setHeight(int height){
        mEndHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            if(mType == EXPAND) {
                mLayoutParams.height =  (int)(mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
            } else {
                mLayoutParams.height = (int) (mEndHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
            }
            mView.requestLayout();
        } else {
            if(mType == EXPAND) {
                mLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                mView.requestLayout();
            }else{
                mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, set your `onclick()` as follows:

```
int height;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(view2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(view2, 1000, MyAnimation.COLLAPSE);
        height = a.getHeight();
        view2.startAnimation(a);
    }else{
        MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(view2, 1000, MyAnimation.EXPAND);
        a.setHeight(height);
        view2.startAnimation(a);
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the same thing to happen in my app. To achieve this:

1. Create a suitable animation in Res/anim. I've used a slide out from left kind of animation. You can google other if you aren't satisfied with this one.

   **slide_out_left.xml**

   ```
   <translate
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
       android:fromXDelta="0"
       android:toXDelta="-50%p" />

   <alpha
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.0" />
   ```
2. Attach animation defined above with view you want to animate, (in your case child1 containing text1 and text2)

   ```
   Animation outAnimation;
   LinearLayout a1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.child1); 

   outAnimation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left);

   a1.setAnimation(outAnimation);
   outAnimation.setAnimationListener(new  AnimationListener() {

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
       a1.setVisibility(View.GONE);                            
       }
       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }                 
   });
   a1.startAnimation(outAnimation);
   ```

**NOTE**: *I've attached animation with child1 instead of text3 because when child1 will slide out slowly it will automatically give an illusion that text3 is sliding in.*

Answer (score 2):

use this animation XML slide_in_left.XML

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

and slid_in_right.XML

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

use this animation 
Animation slideinleft,slideinright;

and initlize this animation

```
public void AnimationInitialization() {

    slideinleft= AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);


    slideinright= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_in_right);

}
```

and call this 2 function for changing visibilty

```
public void showMenu() {

    linearlayout_first.clearAnimation();

    linearlayout_first.startAnimation(slideinleft);

    linearlayout_first.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

public void hideMenu() {

    linearlayout_second.clearAnimation();
    linearlayout_second.startAnimation(slideinright);


    linearlayout_second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

you can change layout as you require.
also change in Xdelta and Ydelta of animation XML..

Comment: Animation in a disappearing view doesn't work without AnimationListener. For this you need to attach an AnimationListener and specify SetVisibility(View.GONE) in onAnimationEnd() !

Comment: Unhides the view and then animates. From my experience it looked really sketchy.

Comment: yes, As android grows with fragment and object Animator so currently we can do with a different way but at that time i have done with this..

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is bit confusing. For `android:animateLayoutChanges`, it says

> ... When this flag is set to true, a default LayoutTransition object will be set on the ViewGroup container and default animations will run when these layout changes occur.

while the documentation of [setLayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition%28android.animation.LayoutTransition%29) method of ViewGroup class says :

> By default, the transition object is null (so layout changes are not
>   animated).

You should try setting a `LayoutTransition` on the layout.

Here is an example that does that.. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UseLayoutTransitiontoautomatetransitionanimationsasitemsarehiddenorshowninacontainer.htm

Comment: I've tried this at first, my second attempt was actually move it to the xml.